# How can I open port 8080 of Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos

How can I open access to port 8080 from the outside world (private lan) on my Mac OS X Lion? I'd like to access a webpage that's running on my lamp stack on my mac (zend server ce) from within the lan. I can access port 80 just fine.  Port 8080 is blocked on the other hand.  I've also disabled the firewall.

Comment: Where are you wanting to accomplish this?  At work or home?

Comment: In any arbitrary lan.

Comment: Is Apache configured to listen on Port 8080 yet?

Comment: Basically when you say 'open a port' its a several step process.  1) Configure & Start your application (ie Apache).  2)  Verify the application is listening on the port:  from commandline netstat -a | grep 8080  3) Turn off firewall(s).  Bottom line is an application needs to be listening on that port for the whole process to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you say that you disabled the firewall, do you mean the one in:
`System Preferences > Security > Firewall`, or the `ipfw`IP Firewall that you can access from the command line? Or perhaps both?

To check to see if you have `ipfw` rules, you can always go to the terminal and type in:

`sudo ipfw list`

You might also use `nmap` to check if the port is open from different places on your internal network. Of course, OS X doesn't comes with nmap by default, so you would have to try that from a Linux machine or use something like [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) or [Macports](https://www.macports.org/) to install it.

`nmap -p 8080 host.domain.com`

I hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - how to open a port. It only suggests ways to check if the port is open.

Answer (score 7):

You can disable firewall or you can allow a certain application to accept incoming connections. Plus to allow access to the outside world (e.g www), you'll need to forward traffic to your internal gateway:port via your router settings.

Here's how to do this:

1. Mac->Sys Preferences->Sharing->Enable “Web Sharing” checkbox
2. Mac->Sys Preferences->Security-> Turn off firewall, or allow your application to accept incoming connection
3. Open a port on the router (via 192.168.1.1) to forward traffic from your_web_ip:port to a local_gateway:port

   1. Router Settings -> Port Forwarding -> create rule: forward to local gateway (e.g. 192.168.1.4), custom port, protocol tcp, source=any, destination=3280, all connection types, forward to port = 8080.

Done. Now from the remote computer, open your browser to your web ip address (find via http://www.whatismyip.com/) + destination port# above, e.g. 72.189.194.65:3280, this will connect to your local 192.168.1.4:8080

Comment: I'm missing the third point: How to access to router settings? I don't find any option on preferences.

Comment: You can get access to your router usually by http://192.168.1.1 with admin name and password.

Answer (score 5):

In MAC OSX - Changing the httpListenAddress for Jenkins on OSX

I installed Jenkins via homebrew and wanted the web interface to be accessible over the network. By default, Jenkins is launched with the `--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1` option and is only accessible on the local machine.

I found the plist file that was used to launch Jenkins in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist` and changed the argument, but each time I ran brew services restart jenkins my changes would be lost. It turns out that this file only exists at run time. The config file that is actually used is located at `/usr/local/opt/jenkins/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`. If you change this file then restart Jenkins then your changes should take effect.

```
sudo vim /usr/local/opt/jenkins/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist
brew services restart jenkins
```

Ref: https://michaelheap.com/changing-the-httplistenaddress-for-jenkins-on-osx/

Comment: 0.0.0.0 if you want to listen on all available interfaces

Answer (score 2):

If the firewall is off and you're sure Apache is listening on :8080, then you must have a firewall upstream somewhere that's blocking 8080. Unblock it there.