# Allow port arbitrary port (such as 5432) open on El Capitan.

Tags: network, macos, firewall

I'm running vagrant and successfully port forwarding from there. My issue is that some ports are not running. I know vagrant is working because I can successfully forward port 80, but cannot forward 5432.

Per these [direction](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31376/how-can-i-open-port-8080-of-mac-os-x-lion/74155), I cannot `sudo ipfw list` as `ipfw` is not found on this OS (El Capitan thing I suppose?).

```
stuff$ sudo ipfw list
sudo: ipfw: command not found
```

I'm running a GUI that is unable to connect to 5432, so I think it's on mac's end.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Please specify your provider (e.g. VirtualBox). Do you have a firewall running?

Answer (score 1):

The ipfw firewall has been replaced by pf in Mac OS X Lion and later. Try looking at the man page for pfctl to start.

An old, but still good [cheat sheet for pf](http://krypted.com/mac-security/a-cheat-sheet-for-using-pf-in-os-x-lion-and-up/)

As for debugging network connections on the Mac, I would run `netstat` to see what ports had listeners. And possibly `sudo lsof -i` to see which process had which port open.