# How can I open a specific port on OS X 10.11.13

Tags: network, macos, command-line

I am currently working with [msfvenom](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/msfvenom/) on OS X. But I wanted to know, the terminal commands to open a specific port say for example 4444. Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: [Unless you have a firewall enabled or that port is in use, I'm not sure why you need to open a given port.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31376/how-can-i-open-port-8080-of-mac-os-x-lion/74155) Can you tell us what's preventing you from using that port?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the terminal command `nc -l 4444` to create a server that listens on port 4444.  However, I think your question really is about opening a port on your router.  If someone else out on the internet somewhere is trying to connect to you on port 4444, the router you have acts as a boundary between you and them, and most often all incoming ports by default are closed.  So even if you run a server on your Mac and it's listening on port 4444, traffic on that port needs to be allowed through at the router level.

Please give us more info so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python to run a simple server that opens whatever port you wish.

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 4444
```

If you have no firewall, the port is now open. Press Control + C to quit the process and close the port again or test the port from your client as needed.

If you have the default firewall, you will be prompted to actually open the port:

[image]

Lastly, if another process has the port open, you'll get an error of the stack trace that ends with the socket error indicating the port is already in use:

```
socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

That's it - ports open on OS X quite easily unless you've made a custom firewall setting.